# Making sense of the FBX export settings in Blender when the FBX files are imported to Unity

Tags: export, unity, .fbx

Exporting a Blender model in FBX using different settings for Forward and Up is not giving expected result when exported to Unity

I have a cube in Blender that I assigned different colors to for each of its sides as shown below.

[image]

I exported the Cube to FBX format using all possible combinations of the Transform's Forward and Up settings as shown below

[image]

When I imported the models to Unity, I see the Cubes from the FBX files in the exact same orientation irrespective of what settings I have used for Forward and Up when exporting from Blender

[image]

Since I've exported the Cube with different Forward and Up values from Blender to FBX files, I was expecting different orientations of the cube when I import the FBX files in Unity, but that is not happening here. Wouldn't the Forward and Up settings when exporting to FBX has no impact on how the models are oriented when imported to Unity?

All the files are available at: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/e78be26ddf55b85e0414b8a2ea238fd620231207110717/b5c95b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is basically not a Blender question (so it will likely be closed) but I guess a lot of people have this confusion when using Blender export, so I'll answer it here.

Have a look (in Unity) at the gizmos and the *Transform* component in the *Inspector* when selecting the game objects one after another and it should become clear. The *Transform* component already contains different (90°) rotation values mapping to the FBX export settings thus all objects appear aligned in the scene.

[image]

You can apply the FBX settings when you select an imported model in the *Project* viewer and tick *Bake Axis Conversion* under *Model* in the *Inspector*. Now the gizmo of the model will match the scene gizmo and the model is oriented as you would expect.

[image]

Comment: When I reset the Transform Component on the Cubes, I could see that they are oriented differently. Thank you for the clarification. However, when I check and apply "Bake Axis Conversion" on all the exported Cubes, they all look the same (even after resetting their Transform Components), so is it safe to say that the "Bake Axis Conversion" undoes the export settings that I used to export the Cubes from Blender?